# How to recover system when wrongly entered command?

Tags: chmod, kubuntu

I wrongly entered

```
chmod -700 /.
```

My entire system collapsed. All applications shutdown automatically. Then I restarted my computer. I could no longer login. What happened, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Was that `chmod -700 /.` or `chmod 700 /.`? I don't expect the former to make much damage, while the latter would be a job for booting a rescue disk and do a `chmod 755` on the root directory of the root filesystem.

Comment: If you are not able to boot up, did you run this as a user using Sudo? 
And you have taken the ownership of files to a userlevel?